# Get properties of a Dynamic Type

Tags: c#, object, model-view-controller, dynamic

I would like to know how to get the properties of my dynamic type.

This is the function to get the List,

```
var result = _files.GetFileContent(reportId).Result;
```

As example I get an object returned like this :

[image]

When I open it, you can see the properties I have :

[image]

The Idea is that I never know the properties. They can change over time. So I want a list which is filled with all the properties. So I can dynamically use them.

How Can I get the properties from the first item (ChargesDelta_DIFF_5, ChargesEfile_RIGHT,ChargesGecep_LEFT, etc)?

Comment: How is `MyDynamicType` declared? How is the collection declared?

Comment: have you tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: It's declared dynamically based on the properties that I receive from a stored procedure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the properties out and convert it to a dictionary:

```
dynamic v = new { A = "a" };

Dictionary<string, object> values = ((object)v)
                                     .GetType()
                                     .GetProperties()
                                     .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(v));
```

Comment: And how can I use my existing dynamic IList<Object> in this?

Comment: What is p? It doesn't help to just introduce unknown variables. That line throws: CS1977 Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. That isn't just an unknown variable, it is the argument to the lambda expression. The code should be fine. Can you create a new question and link it here? Please put in your full code. @harmen

Comment: @Harmen, there was a cast missing. Not sure why it worked before. Maybe I over-generalized it when posting. The fix is to replace `v` with `((object)v)`.

Comment: How is this marked as the correct answer as it doesn't return dynamic properties at all (confirmed on ExpandoObject)?

Comment: @war An expando object can be casted to `IDictionary<string, object>`. This question misused "dynamic" when it is actually just a regular class.

Comment: Yeh, I see what you mean ... what I meant was If you replace the first line with the equiv ExpandoObject the code given doesn't work. In this case the anon object is a concrete type put in a dynamic variable which the compiler still sees concrete type meta for (at least that's my understanding).

Comment: Well, not exactly. But that is subject for another question.

Answer (score 11):

If someone is still struggling with this (as I did), this might be useful.

Let's say `data` is the **dynamic** you want to list all properties from:

This worked for me

```
using System.ComponentModel;

...

dynamic data = new {
    value1 = 12,
    value2 = "asdasd",
    value3 = 98,
    value4 = "pgiwfj",
};

foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(data))
{
    Console.WriteLine("PROP: " + prop.Name);
}

...
```

Then it would output:

- PROP: value1
- PROP: value2
- PROP: value3
- PROP: value4

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/251e4f3d-ce90-444a-af20-36bc11864eca/how-to-get-list-of-properties-of-dynamic-object-?forum=csharpgeneral