# Get List of Fields - dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a very simple use case, I Decode a `json` response received from an API as following

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode(APIContents);
```

This decodes the JSON for me and put it in data object. The only thing I know about this JSON is that this is an array of objects and array is called result. So if I want to get the first item I can simply do the following to get the first item

```
data.result[0]
```

Similarly if I want the ID of first item, I know there is a field in json called id so I can get the ID as following

```
data.result[0].id
```

OR

```
data.result[0].["id"]
```

The problem is, I don't know all the field names, the only field I know is the ID but there are bunch of other fields and I want to read all of them.

How do get the list of all the fields from data.result object if I don't even know each field by name?

What I have tried

**1-** [Loop through an object's properties and get the values for those of type DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656177/loop-through-an-objects-properties-and-get-the-values-for-those-of-type-datetim/36656271)

My code:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in data.result[0].GetType().GetProperties())
{
         // I dont get anything
}
```

**2-** [Get properties of a Dynamic Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613558/get-properties-of-a-dynamic-type)

My code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = ((object)data.result[0])
   .GetType()
   .GetProperties()
   .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(data.result[0]));
```

**3-** Using `PropertyDescriptor`

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(data.result[0]))
{
 // I get nothing
}
```

None of it is working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be, "id", is the only property and there's an encapsulated object instead of other properties? What you're doing in 3, I use all the time to retrieve properties from anonymous objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are operating with Json, would not you consider using something like [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JObjectProperties.htm) instead?

```
JObject o = new JObject
{
    { "name1", "value1" },
    { "name2", "value2" }
};

foreach (JProperty property in o.Properties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " - " + property.Value);
}
// name1 - value1
// name2 - value2

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> property in o)
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Key + " - " + property.Value);
}
// name1 - value1
// name2 - value2
```

Comment: IMHO `JObject` is one of the best choices when it comes to parsing JSON data

Comment: I had to make lots of changes but absolutely using `JObject` worked, thanks for the correct direct.